# Updating value to database based on entry; running on macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where based on the item chosen, a price appears from a database, which has been defined in worksheet 'db'. The Macro I am trying to make compares the value in the current sheet and if it doesn't match that of db Sheet, the db Sheet is updated. In other words, if the user changes the price in the current worksheet, the database is updated correspondingly.

I have tried using for loop to and vlookup to compare the names of items in current worksheet and db and then vlookup the values, but so far when the value is changed in current sheet db is not updated.

```
Sub valueUpdater()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Ret
    Dim Cur

    For Each cell In Range("A9:A20")
        On Error Resume Next
        Ret = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, _
        Worksheets("db").Range("A2:H14"), 5, 0)
        Cur = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, _
        Range("A9:G20"), 4, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Ret <> Cur Then
            Ret = Cur
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Because with `Ret = Cur` you only update the varialbe value in `Ret` but not a sheet value.

Comment: How would you update the sheet value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because with `Ret = Cur` you only update the varialbe value in `Ret` but not a sheet value. Use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) instead of `.VLookup` to get the row number and compare the cell values.

Also you don't need to lookup the `Cur` value because you already have that in `Cell` and you can `.Offset` from there.

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub valueUpdater()
    Dim RetRange As Range
    Set RetRange = Worksheets("db").Range("A2:A14") 'for match you need only the first column where you want to lookup

    Dim RetRow As Double

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Range("A9:A20") 'TODO: specify a sheet for the range!
        RetRow = 0 'initialize
        On Error Resume Next
        RetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cell.Value, RetRange, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If RetRow <> 0 Then
            If RetRange(RetRow, 5).Value <> Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value Then
                RetRange(RetRow, 5).Value = Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```